# What is the correct way to load view from xib?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uikit

All of the resources I have found so far suggest variations of this code for loading a view from `xib` file, but always implementing the same logic:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    var view = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyCustomView", owner: self, options: nil)![0])
    self.addSubview(view as! UIView)
}
```

Which doesn't look right to me because this function belongs to a subclass of UIView, and adds the intended design (`xib`'s design) as a subview. In this case if we added a different UI element to `self`, it would belong to a different parent than the UI elements in the `xib` file.

So the hierarchy would look like this:

```
---self (UIView)  
    ---Other UI elements added by code in `self`
    ---xib (UIView)
        ---UI elements in xib file
```

Isn't this an unnecessary wrapping? If so, is there a way to add all the views in `xib` file to `self` directly? Or is there a different more elegant way of loading design from a `xib` file?

Comment: I find it odd that "all of the resources" you found do it this way. Two things stoke me as unusual: first, the nib is being loaded from within the `init(NSCoder)` constructor. This constructor is typically used when loading from a nib (or storyboard); in other words, it's strange that you'd load a secondary nib when loading from another nib—a nib usually contains the _entire_ view heirarchy. Secondly, the `owner` is typically a view controller, not another view.

Comment: @JamesBucanek Yes that is in fact odd. What I found is that it is possible to assign `self` to the `view` loaded from nib in `objective-c` and that it is how people used to do this. For the second point you highlighted, that is true, but my intention is to create a reusable view which I can add **inside** other views. When you load the nib from a `viewcontroller` you can't add that view into another view, it has it's own screen. I don't see how this is such an overlooked issue: The whole `viewcontroller` practice is based on MVC model yet at the same time it is tedious to create reusables

Comment: that's not true. You can have as many view controllers as you like/need. A view controller can be used to manage any arbitrary subset of views in your view, and are well suited to reusing an MVC pattern in different view hierarchies. I'll illustrate with an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to reuse a complex set of subviews is to define an embedded view controller. You start by defining your top-level view controller. In it, you define an outlet and connected it to an instance of your sub-controller (also defined in the nib). You also connect the sub-controller's `view` to a placeholder `UIView` in the top-level nib's view hierarchy.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var childController: ReusableViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

The slight-of-hand occurs in the sub-controller. Its `awakeFromNib` function gets invoked when the super-controller is loaded. The sub-controller then uses the "placeholder" `UIView` it is connected to to insert it's view hierarchy into the top-level views.

```
class ReusableViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // This controller manages a reusable view defined by a seperate nib.
        // When defined in the parent nib, its view is connected to a placeholder view object.
        // When the nib is loaded, the secondary nib is loaded and replaces the placeholder.
        let placeholder = self.view!
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ReusableViewController", owner: self, options: nil)
        // (the nib connects the view property to the actual view, replacing the placeholder)
        placeholder.superview?.insertSubview(self.view, aboveSubview: placeholder)
        // (do something about constraints here?)
        placeholder.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

The advantage to this arrangement is that the sub-controller can have whatever bindings, outlets, actions, connections, properties, and business logic that it needs, neatly encapsulated and reusable.

This is a bit of a hack because it short-circuits the sub-controller's view-did-load lifecycle (because the controller never loads its own view). To address that, you could define another property that pointed the sub-controller at either a placeholder view or the container view that is should insert itself into. Then replace the `Bundle.main.loadNibName(blah, blah, blah)` stuff with just `let replacement = self.view` and let the view controller do all of the loading.

---

*Here's a finished solution using storyboards contributed by the original poster after getting this to work*

**Using the reusable view in storyboard**
Add a `Container View` (Not to confuse with `View`) to `ViewController` (your main view on storyboard), and set it's scene's (controller) class to the controller we just defined (`ReusableViewController`).
[image: gif]
That's it. This way you can add as many subviews to a view without having to wrap your subviews in storyboards as well as in code.
`Container View`'s intended use is actually documented as exactly for this purpose [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read but couldn't test your answer yet. I am excited to try this, looks promising. I've had a very busy week so I will mark it as answer as soon as I can confirm. Probably in a couple days, or maybe even today

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks. I would like to add though, if I can add to your answer how to use this implementation with storyboards as well, I think that would be a complete solution but since I didn't ask about storyboards in the question I am not sure if it would be appropriate. What do you think? Should I suggest an edit, or should I edit the question first or maybe even add the storyboard implementation to the question itself?

Comment: Using a storyboard wouldn't be a big change. Just define your reusable view controller and sub-views in your storyboard, assign it an identifier, then replace the `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(...` code with `storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier:...`.

Comment: (As I think about it, in retrospect, it's probably not exactly that simple. But I think the general principle would still work. If you get stuck write again and I'll take a stab at sorting out the storyboard details.)

Comment: Actually I meant I know the answer to that :). It's actually much simpler: add a `Container View` (not to confuse with `View`) and set it's `view controller` to the controller we just defined (`ReusableViewController`). That's it. View container's intended use is actually documented as exactly this (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html), which is weird because even Apple's reusable view sample documentations don't mention it at all. I can suggest an edit to explain the storyboard part if you like

Comment: Suggest away and I'll update the answer. If you can't get it into a command, email it to me at james at gloaming dot com.

Comment: Whoa edit was rejected, due to (one of the reviewers' reason for rejecting): `This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive` @RubioRic what is it exactly that you believe I was trying to promote?? @James Bucanek Can you review the edit? My last couple edits were rejected so I am not sure I understand how it exactly works, so I will go with whatever you say. It was clearly useful apparently given that it received an upvote though.

Comment: Sorry @MuhsinFatih, I was out of town and AFK. I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks! :) (btw it's not an alternative, it requires your steps as well)

Comment: I just noticed that loading a nib destroys gesture recognizers added in storyboard. Seems appropriate as they would be bound to the view assigned to `placeholder` and removed. Any ideas other than defining them in code? Just curious

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you implement a xib for a view , it always contains all the needed elements for it . but if you have you can try to add the element like this

```
var view = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyCustomView", owner: self, options: nil)![0]) as! UIView

var lbl = UILabel()

lbl.frame  = //.....

view.addSubview(lbl)

self.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: One can perhaps add new UI elements to the subview loaded from `xib` file, but wouldn't that cause extra effort when scaling, because every individual developer may use different hierarchy? What I mean is that suggested way generally seems like an unnecessary wrapping. I want to mark your answer as correct as you provided a valid implementation, but it doesn't fully address the problem. I will though, if noone else comes up with a better implementation where views are loaded directly to self

Answer (score 0):

You can load the xib of a view during init:

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: Bundle(identifier: "domain.AppName")!)
    self.loadView()
}
```

Is that what your are looking for?

Comment: Which version of swift are you using? I get the following error when I try your answer: `Incorrect argument labels in call (have 'nibName:bundle:', expected 'frame:options:')`

Comment: Are you using this in a `ViewController`? If so, that is not my intention. I used the init functions as implemented in the `UIView`'s class, not it's  controller. Otherwise the view would not be reusable

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer you've wanted all along. You can just create your `CustomView` class, have the master instance of it in a xib with all the subviews and outlets. Then you can apply that class to any instances in your storyboards or other xibs.

No need to fiddle with File's Owner, or connect outlets to a proxy or modify the xib in a peculiar way, or add an instance of your custom view as a subview of itself.

Just do this:

1. Import BFWControls framework
2. Change your superclass from `UIView` to `NibView` (or from `UITableViewCell` to `NibTableViewCell`)

That's it!

It even works with IBDesignable to refer your custom view (including the subviews from the xib) at design time in the storyboard.

You can read more about it here:
https://medium.com/build-an-app-like-lego/embed-a-xib-in-a-storyboard-953edf274155

And you can get the open source BFWControls framework here:
https://github.com/BareFeetWare/BFWControls

And here's a simple extract of the `NibReplaceable` code that drives it, in case you're curious: https://gist.github.com/barefeettom/f48f6569100415e0ef1fd530ca39f5b4

Tom